# Improving performance of batch file reading files and creating a table from them

Tags: performance, batch-file

I created a windows batch file to read all the about 10000 *.txt files (containing a header and 2 tab separated columns of data, 2048 lines) in my folder, creating a text file table by concatenating their 2nd columns. But my approach seems to be quite slow

For this purpose i use for-loops to go through the commands ('TYPE !fileName!') and ('TYPE !fileName! ^| FINDSTR "^[0-9]"'). I first read the second column of a *.txt file. Then store this in a temporary file with a for-loop:

```
SET firstLine=true
FOR /F "delims=  tokens=2" %%G IN ('TYPE !fileName! ^| FINDSTR "^[0-9]"') DO (
    IF !firstLine!==true (
        ECHO %%G > !tmpFile!
        SET firstLine=false
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%G >> !tmpFile!
    )
)
```

afterwards I read the currentTable together with the temporary file and write out to the currentTable file, appending one column

```
SET firstLine=true
(
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('TYPE !currenTable!') DO (
        SET /P line=
        IF !firstLine!==true (
            ECHO %%G    !line! > !currenTable!
            SET firstLine=false
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO %%G    !line! >> !currenTable!
        )
    )
)<!tmpFile!
```

**Edit (due to comments)**

A data file would look like this:

```
some header
col1 col2
12.3 1.2E3
12.4 1.3E3
12.5 1.4E3
```

And what I want will be this

```
some header
col1File1 col2File1 col2File2 col2File3 col2File4 ...
12.3 1.2E3 2.2E3 3.2E3 4.2E3 ...
12.4 1.3E3 2.3E3 3.3E3 4.3E3 ...
12.5 1.4E3 2.4E3 3.4E3 4.4E3 ...
```

where in both cases columns are separated with tabs.

**Questions:**

1) the 'TYPE' command (especially combined with the 'FINDSTR' command) seems to be quite slow. Is there some trick to read the file faster?

**EDIT:** solved, by using only 'FINDSTR' and 'FOR'-loop directly through file, script performance seems to lag at the file write process (due to appending). Any suggestions to avoid the appending (and avoiding troubles with maximum variable size)?

2) Is there some possibility to avoid writing temporary files? Like is there some dummy-stream you can write to and pick from afterwards? I did not find anything like this on the web.

Comment: Try `'MORE !currenTable!'`.

Comment: TYPE and FINDSTR are not slow, but I do see issues with your code that can slow things down. Also, your posted code does not match my understanding of your goal as you stated it. Please provide some sample source file content, as well as an abbreviated version of what you want the output to look like. I think there are much better ways to do what you want, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Note that FOR /F can read the file directly - no need for TYPE. Also, FINDSTR can read a file directly, again, no need for TYPE.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am not sure, if the commands are the problem, as while processing the script gets stucked appending the files. Even within the first few files, one can watch the file size increase in the Windows Explorer. But I will change this redundancy. 
@Nathan Rice: What is the difference of MORE?

Comment: I do not know the bat-possibilities. Can you append all files in 1 large file starting wih the linenumbers in the original file? Than you can find/grep all 0001 lines and combine them to your first record.

Comment: @WalterA: you seem so speak about a very long 3 column file, where first column is the line number of the original file. That one is possible. It is also possible to grep similar line numbers and extract only 3rd argument. **But** as far as I see, you need then to append a file and appending is the slow thing, you can not write a whole line at once i think, neither you can fill a variable and write that out, as variables in batch are size limited.

Comment: I would think the number of files is the main problem. Using this construction will limit the number om temporary files (your question 2).
Can you make a script with a while loop and append the results of the while loop in the target file only once?

Comment: Indeed, it would be only one large file and the table. With **n** lines per file and **N** files (n<N). I would need **n+N** read accesses (where **n** is always the long file ->RAM access) and **nN+n** write accesses (**nN** times with a small string, **n** times for generating long file). My current script reads **3N** (N for generating column files, N for column to table, N times the table) and writes **2nN** (nN to column file, nN to table)... seems faster, i will try that out - but still a lot of writing